# Figaro not loading proper environment in application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment, figaro-ruby

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application. I recently updated to the last Rails version (4.2.3) and I discovered when I run `rake test` it erase my development database. I am using the Figaro gem to declare all my environment variables.

**Here is my application.yml file**:

```
#
# == Database
#
db_host    : 'localhost'
db_username: 'root'
db_password: 'root'

development:
  db_name: 'database-dev' # Not found by Figaro
test:
  db_name: 'database-test' # Not found by Figaro
```

**my database.yml file**:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: <%= Figaro.env.db_username %>
  password: <%= Figaro.env.db_password %>
  database: <%= Figaro.env.db_name %>

  development:
    <<: *default

  test:
    <<: *default
```

If I put `db_name` under the `development` key, I get the message `no database selected` but if I move it to the upper level it works. However `rake test` doesn't use the `test` key either to load the database configuration and erase my development datas.

It was working perfectly before, I don't understand what is wrong.
Thanks for your help.

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.3
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Figaro 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Could you show how you're running the test spec? What environments do you have set-up (in config/environments dir)? Also, what version of RSpec do you run (and do you have rspec-rails gem installed)?

Your `spec_helper.rb` file (or with RSpec 3.x `rails_helper.rb`) should have this line at the top:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
```

If not, trying adding it. Also, you can try to add a print statement for debugging:

```
puts ENV['RAILS_ENV']
```

In general, this should always work, but it's a ugly (and you shouldn't have to do it):

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using rspec, but the default one from Rails. ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test' is properly setup in my test_helper.rb

Comment: I see, so you use Minitest then. If you go to `test/test_helper.rb` you should see the same line. First of all, you should check to make sure that you have two databases created (`mysql -u root`, and then in the console `SHOW DATABASES;`). Normally, when you run `rake db:setup`, the command is executed in *development* env, so (development will be used for creating your test db). You should use `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup`.